# How to describe an operation authorization in AWS Smithy

Tags: idl, smithy

From what I see in some Smithy examples ([1](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-api-specification/blob/23fa274e6b8609db587623d6f1f05346b023bd11/model/ingest/put_pipeline/operations.smithy), [2](https://github.com/wasmCloud/examples/blob/a91db2b9e0563c0234119636b77732cca7d36cd6/interface/payments/payments.smithy), [3](https://github.com/kubukoz/spotify-next/blob/e75c38db0cee81f9a9d3ed91b62bb145a493b13a/app/src/main/smithy/spotify.smithy#L4)) engineers tend to describe operations and input structures without any mentions of *who* or *what* performs them.

For example, if I have the following Smithy definition:

```
@auth([httpBearerAuth])
@http(method: "PUT", uri: "/api/v1/tasks/{id}", code: 200)
operation PutTask {
    input: PutTaskInput
    output: Unit
}

structure PutTaskInput {
    @httpLabel
    @required
    id: TaskId

    @httpPayload
    @required
    body: TaskBody
}
```

I'll get a generated code something like (imaginary Python HTTP Service codegen):

```
class TasksService(HttpEndpoint):
    def put_task(id, body):
        raise NotImplementedError("PutTask operation is not implemented")
```

My question now is how to *idiomatically* state that code needs to look something like following:

```
class TasksService(HttpEndpoint):
    # I need to know who the author is
    # Depending on that I can either refuse the creation (authorize) or create the task in some specific way
    def put_task(author, id, body):
        raise NotImplementedError("PutTask operation is not implemented")
```